# Convergence of a series of independent r.v's iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}<\infty$ for $a_{n} \in (0, 1/3)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Suppose $(X_{n})_{n\geq1}$ is a sequence of independent random variables with $P(X_{n}=2)=a_{n}$; $P(X_{n}=n^{\beta})=a_{n}$; and $P(X_{n}=a_{n})=1-2a_{n}$ with $a_{n}\in (0, \frac{1}{3})$ for all n, and with $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\sum_{n \to 1}^{\infty}X_{n}$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}<\infty$.

I think I have the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_{n}$ implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}<\infty$ part: suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_{n}$ converges. Then, we have a result from Calculus that $\lim_{n\to \infty}X_{n}=0$. By construction, every term $X_{n}$ is either 2, $n^{\beta}$, or $a_{n}$. So, when $a_{n}=0$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}0=0<\infty$.

Going in the other direction ($\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}<\infty$ implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_{n}$ converges I am having a lot of trouble with.

Please help me!

Comment: What does the statement "$P(X_n)=a_n$" mean?  You've said that the $X_n$ are random variables, not events.

Comment: That's a typo. See edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The idea here is that the $a_n$ should be pretty small in order to make $\sum a_n$ converge; this means that the probability that $X_n=a_n$ (and is, therefore, quite small) should be very high.

Do you know the Borel-Cantelli lemma?  It is a very good way to go in situations like this.  See if you can use it to show that the probability that $X_n\in\{2,n^{\beta}\}$ for infinitely many $n$ is $0$. This, in turn, implies that $X_n=a_n$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: I'll give it a go; thanks!

Comment: Oh, you are too, too awesome! How in the fog that was my over-stressed brain I did not see this is beyond me! INFINITE THANKS!!

Comment: @GGG :-)  Happy to help!